# How to start kafka test container before @ContextConfiguration initializers?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, junit5, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

I would like to start kafka test container and obtain it's bootstrap servers:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class, MyApplication.class}, initializers = MyIntegrationTest.Initializer.class)
@Testcontainers
public class MyIntegrationTest {

    @Container
    private static final KafkaContainer KAFKA = new KafkaContainer();

static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(@NotNull ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
        TestPropertyValues values = TestPropertyValues.of(
            "spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=" + KAFKA.getBootstrapServers(),
            "spring.producer.bootstrap-servers=" + KAFKA.getBootstrapServers()
        );
        values.applyTo(configurableApplicationContext);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You should start Kafka container first
at org.testcontainers.containers.KafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers(KafkaContainer.java:65) ~[kafka-1.12.2.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only problem is that to call `start()` method after invoking object

```
private static void startKafkaContainer() {

        KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer();
        kafkaContainer.start();

    }
```

Further information check this [repository](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/modules/kafka/src/test/java/org/testcontainers/containers/KafkaContainerTest.java), please.